# Match and replace the name/value pair of an XML element using XSLT

Tags: xslt, replace, match, xslt-1.0

I am trying to write a match and replace function using XSLT. I've two variable with different name value pairs in it. Few of the name matches in both the variable. I need to replace the values of the matching name value pairs. Example would be:

```
<original_val>xxx=123,iii=kos,123=hfj,i920=owp02</original_val>

<replace_val>xxx=abc,i920=23ew</replace_val>
```

From the above you can see that the

**replace_val**

element does have **xxx** and **i920** name which matches the name **xxx** and **i920** in

**original_val**

element.

My task is to replace the value of xxx and i920 in **original_val** element with the value of **replace_val** element using XSL.  The value of xxx and i920 is totally random. I'm using XSLT version 1. Any tips would be really helpful.

Comment: The best tip would be to upgrade to XSLT 2.0, as then this task becomes much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My tip is to split both strings using a template and create two new variables that contain something like this:

```
<originalSplit>
  <element>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <value>123</value>
  </element>
  <element>
    <name>iii</name>
    <value>kos</value>
  </element>
  <element>
    <name>123</name>
    <value>hfj</value>
  </element>
  <element>
    <name>i920</name>
    <value>owp02</value>
  </element>
</originalSplit>

<replaceSplit>
  <element>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <value>abc</value>
  </element>
    <name>i920</name>
    <value>23ew</value>
  </element>
</replaceSplit>
```

Then you can loop thru the elements of the originalSplit variable and output the name of each.  Then check to see if there is a name match in the replaceSplit variable.  If so, output the replace value.  If not, output the original value.  There are a lot of questions of this site about how to split delimited strings in XSLT 1.0. I suggest using one of those answers.